# changed an incorrect clock. Now code::blocks refuses to build "all is up to date"

Tags: linux, makefile, codeblocks

I fixed (changed) the clock time on a linux CentOs 6.4 computer. When trying to get code::blocks to rebuild, it does nothing even though I changed files, saying everything is up to date. Even clean says nothing to be done.

I thought of using touch, but it does not seem to recognize a recurse parameter. What is a good way to get around this nuissance?

Thanks.

Comment: Clean/build should work...?

Comment: You left out the most critical bit of information: when you changed the time did you change it backwards or forwards?  However, since you say that after you changed source files things didn't rebuild, we must assume you set the clock backward.  That means that even though you changed files, the modification time is still _older_ than the object files that were built from them so make won't rebuild them.  Joe and Joachim's answers are correct: you need to clean out all the old object files and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Either that, or wait for your now-correct clock to catch up to where the old, incorrect clock was.  You don't say how far you had to change it to make it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Completely clean up your build (removing configuration data and object files):

   ```
   make distclean
   ```
2. Reconfigure your build:

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
3. Rebuild:

   ```
   make
   ```

Codeblocks also has a `bootstrap` script that *may* need to be re-executed after `make distclean` and before re-executing `./configure`

Comment: Thank you all. It turns out that I had installed the toolchain version of c++11 on CentOS and somehow had the wrong  path to it. I thought it was the time, but when I changed it by hand it still wasn't working, so then it became obvious. What I still don't get is why I didn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `touch` command on all the source code files.  Use `find` for recursion.

```
/home/user1676605/myproject/src> find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec touch {} \;
```

I hope I got the right command for `find`.

Comment: Using touch won't help.  The OP already said they updated the source files and they weren't rebuilt, so touching more source files isn't going to make a difference.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't seem to work. The timestamp is the same before and after.